# SQL Server Table Partition

Tags: sql-server, partitioning

I have a Table with the following columns

```
ID (INT Primary Key)
RecordDate (DateTime non-unique)
Name (varchar)
```

I have partitioned the table based on field `RecordDate` (Monthly) to different file groups.

Now, how can I add a primary key ID to this partitioned scheme with out combining field with RecordDate?

Comment: What are your requirements such that you need a partitioned table but a logical key that doesn't include your partition scheme fields?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sql Server Primary Key With Partition Issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7655010/sql-server-primary-key-with-partition-issue)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is that your primary key cannot be clustered if you don't want to include your partition column in your primary key as a composite column. So create a clustered index on the partition scheme for RecordDate. Then when you create your primary key constraint, set it to nonclustered.

Please note t[his can degrade performance and cause memory contention](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187526%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and is generally not recommended.

Comment: I have tried to created ID as non-clustered. 

`ALTER TABLE dbo.PartitionTable WITH CHECK ADD CONSTRAINT PK_Container PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED
(ID)
ON PartitionTablePrSc(RecordDate);
GO`

 and I got an error 

`Column 'RecordDate' is partitioning column of the index 'PK_Container'. Partition columns for a unique index must be a subset of the index key.`

Comment: I can create Non Clustered Primary Key on Primary Partition. This slows down my insertion.